# In Perl, How can I print only the values extracted through json?

Tags: json, perl

I have a json file which contains the content. I am opening the json using 
extract_json. i want to access the value of the attribute "d"

```
sub extract_json{
my $file = shift;
local $/;
    open my $fh, "<", "$file";
    my $json = <$fh>;
return $json;
}

my $targetfile = extract_json(' URL of JSON file');
my $object = JSON::XS->new->decode (decode "UTF-8", $targetfile);

my $flat_hash = {
'var'=> $object->{'a'}{'b'}{'c'}{'d'}
 };
```

The content of variable d is ['31', '45'].
I need the value assigned to "var" to be ['31', '45'].

Please help me in getting the desired output.

Comment: what does the above code produce?

Comment: It gives me an error saying that value is not scalar or undefined. 
Do I need to to dereference to get it in scalar context?

Comment: Is it possble that I change the value in json file to d1:31 and d2:45 and extract both values and join them in some way in perl to get the desired output?

Comment: you could try `Dump`ing $object, maybe the structure isnt what you think it is

Comment: It would really help to see the original JSON. Without that, we're just guessing.

Comment: Wait. In `extract_json()` you expect to be passed a filename. But it looks like you're passing a URL to that subroutine. Which is it? A filename or a URL?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use JSON::XS;
my $targetfile = extract_json('file.json');
my $object = JSON::XS->new->utf8->decode($targetfile);

my $flat_hash = 
{
    'var'=> $object->{'a'}{'b'}{'c'}{'d'}
};


sub extract_json{
    my $file = shift;
    local $/;
    open my $fh, "<", "$file";
    my $json = <$fh>;
    return $json;
}

foreach my $key (keys %{$flat_hash}) #Dereferencing hash ref
{

    foreach (@{$$flat_hash{$key}})  #Iterating loop for array ref
    {
        print "$key => $_\n";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

sub extract_json{
        my $file =shift;
        open(my $fh, "<:encoding(UTF-8)" , $file) || die "couldn't open $file";
        local $/;
        my $json=<$fh>;
return $json;
}

my $targetfile = extract_json('example.json');
my $object = JSON->new;
my $decoded= $object->decode($targetfile);

my $flat_hash ={
               'var' => $decoded->{a}{b}{c}->@{d},
     };
 print Dumper $flat_hash;
```